# codeigniter generate mpdf out put to separate tab

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf

In my web application project i need to print a set of payslips in pdf format using MPDF. the user selects month and year in a form and send. then the controller is called (something like create_pdf) and at there all the needed html code is generated and converts it to PDF using "output()" function.
all of the above works fine but the generated pdf is loaded in the same window/tab. But I need to load the PDF to separate window ? how can i do this ? 
I refered some guidelines which use hyperlink with "_blank" but it is not suitable for me because the user pass data to the controller by using a form(POST method)

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code for opening the file or page in new tab.

```
<form action="your_page/your_function" target="_blank">

  //your other input fields

</form>
```